# React - selected value from list is undefined

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

I have a React component `SelectObj` which gets data from my api and passes it to a component `DynamicSelect`.  The DynamicSelect creates a selection list.  When the user selects the option, the selected value should be returned to SelectObj.

DynamicSelect.js:

```
export class DynamicSelect extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    let selectedValue = event.value;
    this.props.onSelectChange(selectedValue);
  };

  render() {
    let arrayOfData = this.props.arrayOfData;

    let options = arrayOfData.map(data => (
      <option key={data.id} value={data.objective_name}>
        {data.objective_name}
      </option>
    ));
    //console.log(options);

    return (
      <select
        name="customSearch"
        className="custom-search-select"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      >
        <option>Select item</option>
        {options}
        {console.log(options)}
      </select>
    );
  }
}

export default DynamicSelect;
```

SelectObj.js

```
import { getObjectives } from "../../actions/assessments";
import { DynamicSelect } from "./DynamicSelect";

export class SelectObj extends Component {
  static PropTypes = {
    objectives: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    getObjectives: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedValue: "Nothing selected"
    };
  }

  handleSelectChange = selectedValue => {
    this.setState({
      selectedValue: selectedValue
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getObjectives();
  }

  render() {
    let arrayOfData = this.props.objectives;

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <DynamicSelect
          arrayOfData={arrayOfData}
          onSelectChange={this.handleSelectChange}
        />
        {console.log(this.state.selectedValue)}
        <div>Selected Value: {this.state.selectedValue}</div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  objectives: state.objectives.objectives
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getObjectives })(SelectObj);
```

The console.log in DynamicSelect prints out the options that I expect, whereas the console.log in SelectObj is undefined. How do I get this selected value from DynamicSelect?

I thought I maybe have to bind my handleChange with `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind.(this)` but that didn't fix this problem (maybe I still should be binding the handleChange?).

Answer (score 0):

```
<DynamicSelect
   arrayOfData={arrayOfData}
   onSelectChange={(e) => this.handleSelectChange(e)}
/>
```

Try to pass your function like this and see whether the result is getting updated.

Comment: Gayathri - same result.